# How can i access the current object in a v-for loop in the same tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Im trying to use the same v-for iteration object in the same tag, i need to get the length of the object

```
<div class="category" v-for="(footerCategory) in footerCategories" :key="footerCategory" :style="`grid-row: span ${footerCategory.footerItems.length}`">
```

Comment: What is happening currently? What errors are you getting in the console? There should be one about not using an object as a key if nothing else.

Comment: not getting an error with the code
`<div class="category" v-for="(footerCategory) in footerCategories" :key="footerCategory">`
the code in the question is what i want, not how it currently is

Comment: i just want access to the (footerCategory) variable lenght in the tag,

Comment: Are you getting the divs? What attributes do those divs have when you inspect them in the dev tools? On the face of it your code looks like it should work but you haven't told us what's currently happening so it's difficult to help. I assume `footerCategory.footerItems` is an array?

Comment: yes an array
Sorry works fine, my bad